# exc_bad_access code=1 When a method call is moved from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Thanks for reading!

I'm new to iOS and following along a tutorial on a chat app communicating via telnet
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

The tutorial is a single view controller with 2 views: the first for joining the chat session, the second for the chat view itself. 
This tutorial is a bit old but I was able to follow along successfully on latest XCode 5.1.1.

What I wanted to do is create a second view controller and be able to specify the IP/hostname and then connect. 
So I moved the call to `[self initNetworkCommunication];` from `viewDidLoad` to a button press from a separate viewcontroller (which is still connected to the same ViewController class as the first view.

I successfully make a telnet connection BUT as soon as I start send messages, I get the **exc_bad_access code=1** error.  I created a button on the first view controller to do the same thing and I encountered no issues....

added this to *ViewController.m* and removed the call from viewDidLoad

```
- (IBAction)connectToServer:(id)sender {
    [self initNetworkCommunication];

}
```

So, how do I avoid this error?

*I have placed my code here https://github.com/ervine13/TelnetChatTest

Comment: Can you post the code where you call `[self initNetworkCommunication];` from the other view controller?

Comment: @ChrisLoonam updated. thanks for reading

Comment: So do you have two separate instances of `ViewController`? Also, are you using storyboards, xibs, or creating the view controller programmatically?

Comment: I am using Storyboards and on that are 2 different ViewControllers. The first, title-less, and the second I titled "Settings". As you can see in viewDidLoad I refer to  it
    `if ([self.title  isEqual: @"Settings"]) {
        [self checkConnection];
    }`

Comment: Just a passerby comment, it's better to use isEqualToString: if you're going to compare strings.

Comment: @ErvinE Can you post your code for the other view controller? Maybe upload your project? This should be pretty easy to debug. I guess your "settings" view controller is just deallocated because nobody has ownership over it and you don't have a model for your connection that you can retain.

Comment: @Chrene I placed my code here https://github.com/ervine13/TelnetChatTest   
thanks for reading

Comment: What line of code is the error occurring on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you have created two global variables, which is generally not a good idea.

Now you load the main view, which is also controlling the popover view controller. This means that two instances of the same view controller class will be instantiated. Now when you press settings and the popover appears, the main view will be deallocated because no one has ownership of it. Therefore you could keep a strong reference to it in `prepareForSegue:` however that is not what I did to make it work.

I followed the singleton pattern and created a simple ServerHelper which holds a shared in- and out-put stream. Then I have created a simple controller for the Connect view, called `ConnectViewController`.

You can download the source here: http://www29.zippyshare.com/d/16861250/9924/TelnetChatTest-master.zip

**Edit**
To connect to the server on the fly go into your `ConnectViewController.m`and add

`[[ServerHelper sharedInstance] connectToIP:self.ipAddress.text port:80];`

to the top of the `connectToServer:`

In the server helper add the following to the `@interface ServerHelper: NSObject`

`- (void)connectToIP:(NSString *)IP port:(int)port;`

Replace the current `setStreamDelegate:` with this:

```
- (void)setStreamDelegate:(id<NSStreamDelegate>)streamDelegate {
    _streamDelegate = streamDelegate;
    self.inputStream.delegate = streamDelegate;
    self.outputStream.delegate = streamDelegate;
}
```

Remove everything the ServerHelper's `init` and implement the following:

```
- (void)connectToIP:(NSString *)IP port:(int)port
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStringRef ipRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)IP;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, ipRef, port, &readStream, &writeStream);

    self.inputStream = (NSInputStream *)CFBridgingRelease(readStream);
    self.outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)CFBridgingRelease(writeStream);

    self.inputStream.delegate = self.streamDelegate;
    self.outputStream.delegate = self.streamDelegate;

    [_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [_inputStream open];
    [_outputStream open];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I no longer get the error. 
I see that in the ServerHelper.m, you connect to the server. It is connecting right on startup. I'd like to specify the IP address before connecting to the server. How do I not connect to the server on startup and instead initiate the connection when I press the "Connect" button? thanks again!

Comment: @ErvinE did you press enter too quick?

Comment: thanks @chrs!!! Works like a champ. Would you mind explaining the difference between the original `setStreamDelegate` method you had versus this one? I also tried doing the same thing by removing the code in the init method to a separate method which worked but the `- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent` wouldn't catch the events. I assume it had something to do with the delegate stuff.... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You create streams in second instance of "ViewController" class. So in first controller input and output streams aren't initialised.

You should create(for example) another controller for popover and create delegate for main controller. After tapping connect button on popover you should sent some message from popover controller to delegate ([delegate connectToServer]), and then init streams in main controller.